# Un componente de primefaces, combo box, no funciona en android

Tags: android, primefaces, combobox

Tengo un problema con un componente en primefaces de combo box que se despliega en computadora, ipad y iphone , pero cuando se despliega en andorid ya sea telefono o tableta se cierra y no permite hacer una seleccion

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y como podemos reproducir tu problema para ayudarte???